# LARAVEL styled password field with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-4

in this form i heve `Form::password()` and i can not styled or embeded class for that. for example this below class and style for `Form::text` can work correctly.

```
{{ Form::text('username', Input::old('username'), array('placeholder'=>'UserName', 'class'=>'form-control' ) ) }}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input id="username" class="form-control" type="text" name="username" placeholder="username">
```

but for `Form::password()` do not work:

```
{{ Form::password('password', null, array('placeholder'=>'Password', 'class'=>'form-control' ) ) }}
```

Generated HTML:

```
<input id="password" type="password" value="" name="password">
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will work:

```
{{ Form::password('password', array('placeholder'=>'Password', 'class'=>'form-control' ) ) }}
```

You don't need the null as you cannot specify a default value for password fields.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks. {!! Form::password('password',  array('placeholder'=>__('staffs.labels.password'),'required'=>'required', 'class'=>'form-control', 'maxlength'=>'32' )) !!}
                    @if($errors->has('password'))
                      <div class="error-message">{{ $errors->first('password') }}</div>
                    @endif

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a custom HTML macro that enables the syntax similar to your first example.

See my answer here:
[How to pass value to Password field in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24886109/how-to-pass-value-to-password-field-in-laravel/29688340#29688340)

Answer (score 0):

**This problem occurred when the null value in the password.**

```
 {!! Form::password('password', old('password'), ['class' => 'form-control ', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Password']) !!}
```

**Please Remove the `old('password')`:**

```
{!! Form::password('password', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Enter Password']) !!}
```