# How to pass value to Password field in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

**I am trying to fetch value of the password field and display it in current form for one of the update pages**

```
{{ Form::label('Password')}} 

{{ Form::password('password',array('class' => 'form-control') }}
```

Laravel blade's password field syntax does not allow parameter for input like it does for text fields for example,

```
{{ Form::label('Email or Username')}} 

{{ Form::text('email',$useremaildata,array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Now I found one solution of using placeholders like that but it is not the rite way of doing it. Sharing just incase.

```
{{ Form::label('Password')}} 

{{ Form::password('password',array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder' => $userpassworddata)) }}
```

Any help will be great.

Comment: Where are you even getting their password from? If you are pulling it from the database, it will be hashed...

Comment: @TheShiftExchange I am getting it from database. Just for the user to reset there password. I have not hashed it yet but I will in the future.

Comment: "I have not hashed it yet" - that is disgraceful security practice. You should always hash your users passwords always. There is no excuse. You should also not be trying to display users passwords ever. If they want to change it - they can change it with a confirm entry, not a display of the current entry.

Comment: Yes I agree with you on that. Thankyou for critiquing

Comment: What about flashing passwords after form validation, sometimes it would be useful to be able to set the password value so the user doesn't require to fill it again. This is a valid use case to be able to set the password input value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simple answer is that you don't do this. Password fields should rarely be pre-filled and so because it's not a common occurrence Laravel doesn't support it.

However, if you *really* want to do this you can use `Form::input()`:

```
Form::input('password', 'name', 'value')
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, it worked Super ! I wish I had enough repo to give you ups :)

Comment: This is bad security practice. The passwords should be hashed in the first place, you shouldnt be doing this.

Comment: sadly this input will not be prefilled if you use `Form::model($myModel)` with `Form::input('password', 'somename', null)`. It prefills all other inputs that have keys in `$myModel` but not the password ones.

Answer (score 1):

I think there are valid use cases for this.  In my case, I am storing the password for another system, and when the user edits, I want to load the prior value from the database and fill it, so it doesn't get cleared when the user saves.

Here's a custom HTML macro that allows you to set a default value in the password field.

In `start/global.php` do:

```
/**
 * Custom macro for a masked password field with a default value
 */
 HTML::macro('passwordWithDefault', function($name, $defaultValue = "", $optionsArray) {    
    return Form::input('password', $name, $defaultValue, $optionsArray);
 });
```

Then in your HTML or template, you can use it like so:

```
HTML::passwordWithDefault('pwdField', Input::old('pwdField', $pwd_value),['class' => 'form-control'])
```

Comment: Simpy don't save the user password field when it is empty, Save the password only when it has all the validations (not empty, min length etc)